# Cycles GPU Glitched Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I encountered this glitch(?) when I rendered this project of mine using GPU Compute in Cycles Render and I really don't know how to do it, it always shows in any projects.

[image: GPU Rendered Image]
but when I'm using the CPU, the image is okay. So, what should I configure to fix this error?

[image: CPU Rendered Image]

The device I'm using is a Lenovo ideapad 110 Laptop

Comment: check to be sure your normals are pointing the correct way.

Comment: update the drivers for the gpu